# How to refresh the fragment inside view pager instantly in android

Tags: android

I post some thing in home fragment.If i will give the likes to my post means i does not display immediately in my profile page.My profile page is similar to google plus.It take time to load the likes but if i Post anything means it does not displayed immediately in my profile fragment.

Comment: Any one answer me soon i had struggled from past three days

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please add more clarification. You should also add some code snippet of what you are trying to do.